# Detect role in Postgresql dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have been trying to create a script that detects that a role already excists and if it does it should revoke all privileges. This works fine doing it like this:

```
DO $$DECLARE count int;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO count FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'superman';
IF count > 0 THEN
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE FROM superman;
END IF;
END$$;
```

But now I want this to be dynamic per environment since I will be using different role names per environment. So I tried to use the \set mechanism but that doesn't seem to work when using pl/sql so if I would do something like the following Postgresql is complaining with syntax errors:

```
/set environment _int

DO $$DECLARE count int;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO count FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'superman';
IF count > 0 THEN
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE FROM superman:environment;
END IF;
END$$;
```

Although if I would not do it in pl/sql the revoke statment works just fine. So my question is how can I make my script dynamic by passing parameters to it so they will be replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for dynamic SQL. Also, a `DO` statement cannot take parameters. Create a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_revoke_all_from_role(_role text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = _role) THEN
    EXECUTE 'REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE x FROM ' || quote_ident(_role);
END IF;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_revoke_all_from_role('superman');
```

- `IF` block is simpler with `EXISTS`.
- I use [`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to avoid SQLi.
- The table name could be the second parameter of the function ...

Comment: Ah ok.. Thnx!! I will try this out. I was already afraid to have to do it like this. I find it weird though since in Oracle it is possible to pass variables from the outside to a plsql script without having to write a function. I just want this logic in there so I can do a deployment of my database. Why do I have to create a function for this? Isn't there any other way of doing it like in Oracle?

Comment: @user1515731: I wouldn't know of any. The plpgsql function doesn't seem to complicated, though, or does it?

Comment: No it's not indeed but I don't like the fact that I have to create a function just to detect if a role exists and basically drop it afterwords since I won't be using it in my application. But I will try it out thnx for your help :-)